# How to reference another project with controllers but not enable their routes?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a legacy controller which I want to be a wrapper on the new controller (since for this particular API the legacy and current versions are the same). However when I reference the project of the new service, all of the routes of the new service are also available. So essentially I want only the routes from the current assembly to be configured.

Is this possible by cleanly specifying some option? I can see other questions where people are trying to go the other way (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474982/web-api-controller-in-other-project-route-attribute-not-working?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)), but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace the `IHttpControllerTypeResolver` service in your HttpConfiguration and only select the `type` of controllers you want.

Here's a sample which return only the controllers which are in the same assembly with `HttpControllerTypeResolver`

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new HttpControllerTypeResolver());

private class HttpControllerTypeResolver : IHttpControllerTypeResolver
{
    public ICollection<Type> GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver _)
    {
        var httpControllerType = typeof(IHttpController);
        return typeof(HttpControllerTypeResolver)
            .Assembly
            .GetLoadableTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && httpControllerType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```